# Geocoding with OpenLayers?

Tags: geocoding, openlayers-2

How can I achieve Geocoding with the JavaScript OpenLayers API, in the same fashion as the Google Maps API?

Comment: What do you want to geocode? In what language? Do you have an example what you want to achieve....?
Did you take a look at: http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.10/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers-js.html

Comment: i need to get latitude, longitude from the given address, like google geocode...

Comment: You can still use the Google Geocoding API - if you stay under 2500 reqs per day, it's free to use. You'd have to tie it in with your web application somehow. Is your question really how to do that? If so, we need more context. What do you want to achieve? What do you already have?

Comment: Also, there's alternatives that may be just as well suited to your needs: the MapQuest Open geocoder based on OpenStreetMap data, for example. http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/nominatim

Comment: Thanks @mvexel, i need to get latitude, longitude from given address for any country, i have done this with google maps api, but i need any free geocoding api, thats why i turned to OpenLayers, but geocoding is not possible with OpenLayers..

Comment: Well like I said, Google is still free for limited use, and I gave you a link for one alternative. There's also Yahoo PlaceFinder http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/ (don't know about the usage restrictions for that), and likely others.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is too broad. It is fairly simple - what other services are there, that provide geocoding, similar to Google Maps and work through OpenLayers. Thanks for Google Maps suggestions but the OP is asking for *alternatives*. I'm aware of GeoNames and Bing Maps API, for example. Is that too broad?

Answer (score 6):

Openlayers does not feature a Geocoding API. There are [several questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geocoding) here related to geocoding. Some of them specifically mention [openlayers and geocoding](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=openlayers%20geocode) (many do so with Google).

Comment: is there any alternative is there? i am using openlayers, so what would be the best possible way?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Google Geocoder with OpenLayers, for an example see this post:

[How to use Google Maps V3 Geocode with Openlayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21045/how-to-use-google-maps-v3-geocode-with-openlayers/24870#24870)

Disclaimer: as someone pointed out you might be in violation of their usage terms, but I'll leave that for you lawyer to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Possible way,
Try to find any other free/commercial geocoder.  Once you geocode the address, still you can you use your openlayer to overlay the lat.longs on the map tiles.

Comment: can u suggest any free geocoder.

Answer (score 0):

http://geocoder.us/help/

"geocoder.us find the latitude & longitude of any US address - for free"

hope you are trying for US addresses...

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i am trying for whole world, is there any thing?

Answer (score 0):

Using openlayers 3, you will have the opportunity to use a series of servers. OSM or photon as usual is of preference (I will personally go for this especially with a limited budget), though using the Mapquest or Google geocoder you will need a key. I will refer you to: https://github.com/jonataswalker/ol3-geocoder. It will be very helpful!