# How to use Google Maps geocoding with Openlayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps, geocoding, address

I'm making a Openlayers map with some shapefile and I have Google Maps base layer. I want to create a text area and a button. When I input a address and click the button, the map should show me the google maps address in the map. Can you help me please ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21045/how-to-use-google-maps-v3-geocode-with-openlayers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is my code

```
<script src='http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=ABQIAAAAjpkAC9ePGem0lIq5XcMiuhR_wWLPFku8Ix9i2SXYRVK3e45q1BQUd_beF8dtzKET_EteAjPdGDwqpQ'></script>

function search(){
    //alert('search start');
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value+",Kathmandu, Nepal";
    //alert(address);
    var geocode_url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address="

    //needs google api
    var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
    //geocoder.setBaseCountryCode('Nepal');
    var location = geocoder.getLatLng(address,
        function(point) {
            if (!point) {
                alert(address + " not found");
            } else {
                //alert("going to "+address);
                var loc = new OpenLayers.LonLat(point.x,point.y);
                map.setCenter(loc,3);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code.

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {

```
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
           console.log(results[0].geometry.location);                              
        }
        else {
             console.log("Geocoding failed: " + status);                            
        }
    });
```