# Geocoder of Google Maps on OpenLayers map

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps, geocoding

I'm trying to integrate the geocoder of Google Maps into my ol-map. There are a lot of similar questions asked. I tried out this: http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/topp/almanac/examples/geocoder.html example but it doesn't work. Looking through: [How to use Google Maps geocoding with Openlayers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53005/how-to-use-google-maps-geocoding-with-openlayers) also didn't help me.

(As I'm new here I cannot comment on peoples answers so I thought it might be OK to open a new question - tell me if I'm wrong) See code below for my attempt. Do you have any tips or know any working example?

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Google styled in OL mit kml</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="OpenLayers-2.12/theme/default/style.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="OpenLayers-2.12/theme/default/google.css" type="text/css">
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>
<script src="OpenLayers-2.12/lib/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    html, body {
        height: 100%;}
    #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 80%;
        border: 1px solid black;}
    .olPopup p { margin:0px; font-size: .9em;}
    .olPopup h2 { font-size:1.2em; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var lon = 5;
    var lat = 40;
    var zoom = 5;
    var map;
    var geocoder;
    var markersLayer;
    var add1 = "1600 Amphitheatre Pky, Mountain View, CA";

    function init(){
    var options = {projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
        displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")};

    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', options);
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google", {sphericalMercator:true});
    markersLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Suchergebnis");
    map.addLayers([gmap, markersLayer]);

    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());

    map.zoomToExtent(
        new OpenLayers.Bounds(
            68.774414, 11.381836, 123.662109, 34.628906
        ).transform(map.displayProjection, map.projection));
    }
    function search(){
//alert('search start');
var address = document.getElementById('address').value+",Kathmandu, Nepal";
//alert(address);
var geocode_url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address="

//needs google api
var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
//geocoder.setBaseCountryCode('Nepal');
var location = geocoder.getLatLng(address,
    function(point) {
        if (!point) {
            alert(address + " not found");
        } else {
            //alert("going to "+address);
            var loc = new OpenLayers.LonLat(point.x,point.y);
            map.setCenter(loc,3);
        }
    }
   );
  }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
 <h1 id="title">OSM + Google Maps + KML Reprojection</h1>
 <input id="address" type="textbox" value="Sydney, NSW">
 <input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="search()">
 <div id="map" class="smallmap"></div>
 <div id="docs"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you say "doesn't work" and "didn't help me", please explain what happened, and what happened instead.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your search() function should look like this:

```
    function search(){
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value+",Kathmandu, Nepal";

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var loc = new OpenLayers.LonLat(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng())
            map.setCenter(loc, 3);

          } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
          }
    });
}
```

Other than this, in your example you seemed to have mixed the deprecated google maps api v2 code with the openlayers code.